# Highcharts - Export button options offset using a little div

Tags: highcharts

Please refer to the screenshow below:

[image]

When I click on the green arrow to drop down the export options, the options are nearly completed hidden outside the div.

How can I adjust the offset?

An example here: http://jsfiddle.net/L76yV/

This occurs when the div has little time. Like this:

```
<div id="container" style="height: 170px"></div>
```

Comment: Loooks lile a bug, reported [here](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1985). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My solution for this was put the button on the bottom container.